# How to keep the url saved after editing the post in forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, url

I am working on a rails app. I have a form for new post that includes title, image, URL link, and a description. However, i faced an issue and that is whenever the user tries to update(edit) the post, the URL link disappears. The user has to rewrite the URL link everytime he has to update the post!

Here's my edit.html.haml:

```
.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
    .row
        .panel.panel-default
            .panel-heading
                %h1 Edit Project
            .panel-body
                = simple_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
                    - if @post.errors.any?
                        #errors
                            %h2
                                = pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error")
                                prevented this Post from saving
                            %ul
                                - @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                                    %li= msg

                    .form-group
                        = f.input :title,:label => "Project Name", input_html: { class: 'form-control', :type => "text", :required => ""}

                    .form-group
                        = f.input :image,:label => "Image", input_html: { class: 'form-group',"aria-describedby" => "fileHelp", :required => "", :type => "file" }

                    .form-group
                        = f.input :link,:label => "Project Link", input_html: { class: 'form-control', :type => "url", :value => "https://", :required => "" }


                    .form-group
                        = f.input :description,:label => "Description", input_html: { class: 'form-control', :rows => "3", :required => "" }


                    %button.btn.btn-info{:type => "submit" } Update Project
```

Here my `posts_controller.rb`:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :most_liked]

    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def most_liked
        @most_liked = Post.all.order(cached_votes_score: :DESC)
    end

    def show
        @comments = Comment.where(post_id: @post)
        @random_post = Post.where.not(id: @post).order("RANDOM()").first
    end

    def new
        @post = current_user.posts.build
    end

    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)


        respond_to do |format|
            if @post.save
              flash[:success] = 'YEs'
              format.html { redirect_to @post }
              format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
            else
              flash[:danger] = 'no'
              format.html { render :new }
              format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        respond_to do |format|
            if @post.update(post_params)
              flash[:success] = 'Good'
              format.html { redirect_to @post }
              format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
            else
              flash[:danger] = 'bad'
              format.html { render :edit }
              format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    def upvote
        @post.upvote_by current_user
        redirect_to :back
    end

    private

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :link, :description, :image)
    end

end
```

I could not find something similar to my question, please help! Thanks

Comment: The URL link disappears, or they are redirect? What is in the browser? Can you post the controller for this?

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by redirect? The URL link is part of the form but whenever the user try to update the already existing post that has a URL link in it. After the update the URL link becomes blank. I am doing this in Chrome. I also added my posts controller, Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using :value you are overwriting the value of that field that would be placed in there.  You can use :placeholder instead.

Change this line

```
= f.input :link,:label => "Project Link", input_html: { class: 'form-control', :type => "url", :value => "https://", :required => "" }
```

to use a placeholder instead of a value like this

```
= f.input :link,:label => "Project Link", input_html: { class: 'form-control', :type => "url", :placeholder => "https://", :required => "" }
```